# XCUIApplication in usual osx app?

Tags: macos, testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, ui-testing

A new possibility was introduced in xcode 7 - "Record UI Test" button. This button allows you to write your actions as code automatically.

The problem is this feature is available in tests only. But what if I want to use it in the app as a bot which navigates through window elements and can interact with them? My current solution is implemented via `CGEventRef` and it is very buggy. And I can't even insert `XCUIApplication` call into my app because I don't know which files I should include.

How to use commands from tests target in another non-test target and is it possible to solve in general?

P.S. I can't just call, for example, button handlers because my bot also interacts with another app window.